# Why isn't this C++ loop counting from 10 to -5?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, counting, negative-number

Alright, so I'm learning C++ and one of the challenges was to make a program that counts down from 10 to -5.. it's always going from 9 to 1, and it says Done!

Please help me in any way you can, and here's the code:

```c
/*
*
*   Negative Example
*
*/
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
signed int i = 10;
    for(i <= 10 && i != (0 - 5); --i;) {
        using std::cout;
        cout << i << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Done!" << std::endl;
}
```

The output: 
9 
8 
7 
6 
5 
4 
3 
2 
1 
Done!

Comment: Review the parts of a for loop.

Comment: A for-loop must have three three parts: `for (initialization ; condition ; step)`. In your code, the step is the second one, and the third one is empty.

Comment: What's the initialization, defining a variable within the loop?

Comment: Yes. You can skip it by just putting a semicolon.

Comment: Yes. But if you declare/initialize the variable before the loop, you can leave the first part empty as well. In that case it becomes `for ( ; i > -6 ; --i)`.

Comment: @AdamOrama Yes.  `for(int i = 10; (i <= 10) && (i != -5); --i)`

Comment: The loop ends when `--i` results in `0`.

Comment: @MarkGarcia Therefore that's FALSE in a bool, how would I go about overriding that?

Comment: @AdamOrama `i` is *implicitly* converted to a boolean value. When `i` becomes `0`, it is implicitly converted to the boolean value `false`. That value would then be used for the condition part of the `for` loop.

Comment: Also, you really shouldn't spend your time trying to invent obscure loop conditions.

Comment: @SamDufel It's for learning C++, I missed that part sir. Thanks for your EVER so VALUED opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you have misplaced the parts of the `for` loop.
As it is, the loop begins by evaluating the condition, and then proceeds to decrement `i` each time through, and check that this `i` is not equal to zero. The fact that your code completes is a consequence of the fact that `--i` will evaluate to `0` (false) if `i == 1`.

Your code should look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    // Move the variable initialization to the first part of the loop
    signed int i;

    // Note the difference in where the expressions are placed
    // relative to the semicolons.
    for(i = 10; i <= 10 && i != (0 - 5); --i) {
        using std::cout;
        cout << i << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Done!" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @AdamOrama No problem! By the way, you're allowed to write things like `-5` instead of `(0 - 5)`. Also, it's considered good practice to write `i > -5` rather than `i != -5`.

Answer (score 2):

As @jogojapan suggests, you want to rewrite

```
 for(i <= 10 && i != (0 - 5); --i;) {
```

as

```
for(i = 10 ; i != (0 - 5); --i) {
```

preferably as (although no difference functionally)

```
for(i = 10 ; i > - 5; --i) {
```

You can also define `i` within the loop body itself, if it is not needed before or after it, like so

```
for(int i = 10 ; i > - 5; --i) {
```

Edit: Change `i>-5` to `i>=-5` if you want the loop to run with `i=-5` as well.

Comment: `for(i = 10 ; i > - 5; --i)` Not working..

Comment: @AdamOrama Not working meaning? Is it missing the -5 and you need the -5?

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i <= 10 && i != (0 - 5); --i;) {
```

You have those statements in the wrong place, it should be:

```
for(;i <= 10 && i != (0 - 5); --i) { // or (0 - 5 - 1) if you want -5 as well
```

The reason it's starting at 9 and terminating at 0 is because you're using `--i` as the *continuing condition.*

That condition has a side-effect that it decrements `i` *before* the loop body runs (ie, starts at 9) and it will be false the instant it hits 0.

For a better understanding, consider `for (x;y;z)`:

- `x` is performed *once* before the first iteration.
- `y` is is evaluated before *each* loop iteration and, if true, the loop continues (false means the loop exits).
- `z` is performed after each iteration of the loop.

Of course, if you want a loop that counts from 10 to -5 (inclusive), just use:

```
for (int i = 10; i >= -5; i--)
```

and stop messing about with dodgy code :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you mismatched the middle term.  The foreach loop as 3 terms inside the parenthesis and even if you dont use them, you still need 2 semicolons.  Your middle term is currently --i which will return false only when i is 0.

Also, the for loop in C++ unlike C has a different initialization portion to the for loop whereas in C, you have declare like this . . .

```
int i;
for (i=0; i < 10; ++i)
```

In C++ you can declare the variable inside of the loop as such . . .

```
for (int i=0; i < 10; ++i)
```